# Troubling in setting IE homepage

Tags: browser, adware, bloatware

I am having trouble in changing IE homepage. Everytime I change my home page to google.com or default it changes my home page into annoying one called http://go.speedbit.com/?pid=s What the heck this? Also this thing is now trasfered into my Firefox browser. I don't know what that search bar is it is neither Bing nor Google. Could any one help me. I am using IE 11 also firefox latest version

I update Windows Important Updates but Optional Updates

PC Specs:

**Windows 7 64bit**

Aspire E1 431

EDIT: yes I once downloaded SpeedBit Accelerator but now I have uninstalled it. But it still shows in my **regedit**. I am hestating to delete it since my browsers still freezes and showing not *responging error* on top of the browser windows [ I currently use IE and Firefox. I recently deleted Opera and Chrome since this not responding error shows in all my browsers.] **My RAM is 2GB** and when I go to Task Manager It shows **Physical Memory is 77%**.

Comment: Reset the browser or create a new profile. Also see [this](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc).

Comment: @karan how do I create a new profile in IE11 and if I reset  my broser  what are the negative consequence, becoz IE says u have to do it when ur browser is in unusable state.

Comment: New profile is for Firefox which supports it. Both browsers allow you to reset all settings back to defaults. Negative consequences would be any custom settings getting deleted and needing to be reconfigured. You should also back up your favourites, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to try in this case.

1)Reset your IE browser completely.  Backup your favourites etc and then go to control panel > internet options > Advanced > Reset

2)AV/Malware/Spyware scans - lots of them.  Try Adaware, Malwarebytes, Avast etc.. install one, update it completely and scan/clean until it comes up clean.  Uninstall it and then move onto the next one.

3)Reinstall your browser completely (Uninstall IE updates, turn off the "Internet Explorer" feature, reboot, reinstall the feature and updates.

4)Attempt running microsofts fixit for IE (available at www.microsoft.com/fixit) and select IE and try "Fix Internte Explorer issues to make IE fast, safe and stable"

Comment: How about my firefox browser . Now when I start to watch Youtube video it never loads the video. Same thing happened to my Opera browser an Chrome .What happened to chrome was when I click to youtube video it starts the video but within few seconds it dies off.  That’s why I deleted opera and chrome ,I thought I was running out of  RAM. But this  still happening  to IE and Firefox. I mean  Not  Responding error  is hanging on top of the window.

Comment: browse to about:config, click the confirmation button and search for  "Home".  Also, firefox and IE are knownt o go non-responsive while playing flash.  Try disabling your Flash player on Firefox and see if browser performs better.  If it does, reinstall flash.

Comment: you said "Uninstall IE updates " what do you mean by that ? I mean I  always update Windows. and my version is IE11. and the other thing u mentioned was Micros fixit , isn't this extention going to cause symptoms further extent

Comment: MS Fixit is a standalone program that will try to fix it.  You can uninstall microsoft updates from Control panel > programs and features > installed updates prior to reinstalling IE to make the process less likely to fail

Comment: are u sure unistalling an update wont cause a futher problem. I went MS Fixit site but it says this applies to IE 7 and 8

Comment: If you do it properly, it shouldn't cause any problems at all.